# MySQL Select Duplicated Data By The Latest Update Time

Tags: mysql, sql

I got a question about mysql query.
So here is the problem.
I have table with this structure.

```
categoryName | checkinDate | checkoutDate | roomPrice | roomService | insertTime.         | updateTime
cat1         | 2015-05-12  | 2015-05-13   | 300,000   | breakfast   | 2015-05-13 12:33:21 | 0-0-0 00:00:00
cat1         | 2015-05-12  | 2015-05-13   | 320,000   | wifi        | 2015-05-13 12:33:22 | 0-0-0 00:00:00  
cat1         | 2015-05-12  | 2015-05-13   | 350,000   | breakfast   | 2015-05-13 12:33:22 | 2015-05-13 12:36:12    
cat1         | 2015-05-12  | 2015-05-13   | 390,000   | wifi        | 2015-05-13 12:33:22 | 2015-05-13 12:36:33
```

How can I obtain the latest updated data like this :

```
cat1 | 2015-05-12 | 2015-05-13 | 320,000 | breakfast | 2015-05-13 12:33:22 | 2015-05-13 12:36:12    
cat1 | 2015-05-12 | 2015-05-13 | 320,000 | wifi      | 2015-05-13 12:33:22 | 2015-05-13 12:36:33
```

But to be noted, the newest list of updated cat1 is not always in the same amount from the previous updated cat1.

How can I achieved this.

I have tried this query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  hotel_id = 1
```

and

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable 
WHERE  hotel_id=1 
AND    in 
       ( 
              select max(updatetime) 
              FROM   mytable)
```

But unfortunately, Both of them doesn't fulfilled my requirement.

Any idea guys?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Can you confirm your PK?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT
   categoryName,
   checkinDate,
   checkoutDate,
   roomPrice,
   roomService,
   insertTime,
   updateTime 
FROM   mytable
WHERE  hotel_id=1 
   AND updateTime IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY updatetime ASC
```

Comment: Thanks for rejecting my edit.  Real nice.  Great answer dude, really easy to read.  Your the best.

Comment: Little correction, I don't need checking updateTime IS NOT NULL since the data already sorted by ascending..I just need even not updated data is being selected too. But, thanks for your answer...

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM   table t1 
       LEFT JOIN table t2 
              ON t2.categoryname = t1.categoryname 
                 AND t2.roomservice = t1.roomservice 
                 AND t2.updatetime > t1.updatetime 
WHERE  t2.categoryname IS NULL
```